# postgres select all tables in the current search path?

Tags: postgresql

I need to find all the *visible* tables in my current schema search path.  I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_tables
AND schemaname IN (SHOW search_path)
```

but it errors with:

`PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "search_path"
LINE 3:    AND schemaname IN (SHOW search_path)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pg_*_is_visible()` set of functions is provided for this purpose.  Here is one way to use them:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE relkind IN ('r', 'v') AND pg_table_is_visible(oid);
```

Comment: This unfortunately includes all `pg_catalog` tables even if that schema isn't explicitly in the search path :/

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current schemas using `CURRENT_SCHEMAS()` function. It will resolve any references in the search path for you (e.g. `$user`)

```
 SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = ANY (CURRENT_SCHEMAS(false));
```

You could also use the more standard [information_schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/information-schema.html) pseudo-schema.

```
 SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = ANY (CURRENT_SCHEMAS(false));
```

Comment: This doesn't address the case where some equally named tables are hidden by other tables earlier in the search path.

Comment: Peter, I don't quite follow your objection, can you explain a little more?

Comment: @SooDesuNe: Peter's point is the query I posted will return tables with matching names on different schemas. The search_path stops looking when it finds the first match, so if search_path is `a,b` and table `foo` is in both schemas, normal search path resolves `foo` to `a.foo` because `a` schema is first in the search_path.